# need to split some linestrings by points

Tags: postgis, point, linestring, splitting

please help me, i'm new in gis

1) i have а table with geom railways, which are multilinestrings (for example there are 2 ways one of which is interrupted, so this way will be multilinestrings consisting of many linestrings, wich have the same ID)

2) i have a table with points, which is on the line, but not in the linestring itself, i.e. each point is not a vertex of the linestrings
[image]

i need to split lines by points in this case (when 1 way is a multilinestring consisting of many linestrings, look at the picture below, column 'glput' is ID of the way)

an illustration of what I have and what i need
[image]
blue lines are segments that i must have

i try to use ST_LineSubstring (roads.geom, ST_LineLocatePoint (poits.geom1), ST_LineLocatePoint (points.geom2))

full query:

select ST_LineSubstring(st_geometryn, ST_LineLocatePoint (st_geometryn,geom1), 
ST_LineLocatePoint (st_geometryn,geom2)) 
from table_road t1 
join table_point t2 
on t1.glput=t2.glput

but it is not working as it should, because ST_LineLocatePoint representing the location of the closest point on EACH of linestrings with the same ID, but it must interpolate point only to the line on which they lie

Comment: Please consider editing your question (just click edit below the question) instead of leaving important detail in comments where they could be hidden when other information is added.

Comment: I have solved this problem with the function ST_Dwithin(st_geometryn,geom1, 50). If is it true, then point lie on the line and ST_LineLocatePoint take this point, else it does not take the point. But I was faced with another problem. Coordinates of each  linestring take the start from different vertex, i.e. coordinates not in series. here an illustration:  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/iP2Yv.png

Comment: And ST_LineLocatePoint return float 1st argument more then 2 argument. you may notice that 1 and 2 records in the table belong to one line, 3,4,5....8 records belong to another line. here an illustration:
  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/wlbwX.png Two last columns are results of  work function ST_LineLocatePoint and they are right only for  3,4,5....8 records, but for 1,2 records  it returns float in reverse